# Android Studio library module build errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project that will not build in Android Studio (builds fine in Eclipse). 
 The issue is with the library modules. The project setup is as follows:
 App project (has dependency on all other modulus)
 Library Module A (Domain Layer, has database business objects etc.)
 Library Module B (dependency on Module A, contains views workflow pertaining to B)
 Library Module C (Dependency on Module A, contains views and workflow pertaining to C)

As stated, this works fine in Eclipse (probably because of a different build system - not Gradle)

When moving to Android Studio (latest verstion 1.1.0) I gradually moved the modules over App, then A, then B, then run and everything works great. Added C, but gradle build will not work as module C cannot fine the R file for Module B (I have some share generic layouts).
 However, the IDE has no issues at all. This lead me to suspect that it is an issue with the Gradle build scripts, possibly not moving the module B R-File where it can be found.
 The gradle build error is:
 error: package moduleA.R does not exist
 This error is only when building moduleC

App dependencies section of Gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':moduleA')
compile project(':moduleB')
compile project(':moduleC')
}
```

dependencies for Module C:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
provided project(':moduleA')
}
```

Setting.gradle: (:daogenerator is just for greeendao stuff)

```
include ':app', ':moduleA', ':daogenerator', ':moduleB, ':moduleC'
```

The one thing I do notice is in the app.iml file the orderEnty looks off, but this is generated by the IDE so any edits are over written:

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 21 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
<orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="appcompat-v7-21.0.3" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="opencsv-2.0" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="greendao-1.3.7" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-21.0.3" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-annotations-21.0.3" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="moduleC" exported="" />
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="moduleA" exported="" />
<orderEntry type="module" module-name="moduleB" exported="" />
```

Somehow I would expect the orderEntry for ModuleC to be after ModuleA; however, I don't know of to specify that.

The following are some Gradle debug statements just before the error:

```
08:34:42.738 [DEBUG][org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':moduleC:compileDebugJava' is up-to-date
08:34:43.007 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Executing task ':moduleC:compileDebugJava' (up-to-date check took 0.269 secs) due to:
Output file C:\Dev\Fieldbook\build\intermediates\classes\debug\moduelC\BuildConfig.class has been removed.
Output file C:\Dev\Fieldbook\build\intermediates\classes\debug\moduleC\R$attr.class has been removed.
Output file C:\Dev\Fieldbook\build\intermediates\classes\debug\moduleC\R$styleable.class has been removed.
08:34:43.009 [DEBUG]org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':moduleC:compileDebugJava'.
```

I have not tried to build outside of the Android Studio, may attempt that when I get time. In the meantime I'm just put the port on hold and continue to develop in Eclipse

Comment: are you sure to use provided project(':ModuleA') instead of compile project(':moduleA')?

Comment: The module names in my actual project are different, I just changed them here in the question. So that error only exists in the question and not in the actual project. If there were such an error in the actual project, my build errors would be much worse. (I fixed the question)